# How can I get recipient ip address and location when Recipient opens my mail?

Tags: c#

How can I get client ip and address when client open my mail? I tried this:

```
 var ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"] ?? HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
 IpInfo ipInfo = new IpInfo();
 string info = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://ipinfo.io/" + ip);
 ipInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IpInfo>(info);
 RegionInfo myRI1 = new RegionInfo(ipInfo.Country);
 obj.country = myRI1.EnglishName;
 obj.countryCode = myRI1.ThreeLetterISORegionName;
 obj.state = ipInfo.Region;
 obj.city = ipInfo.City;
 obj.ip = ipInfo.Ip;
```

But this returns my host server Address

Comment: Does this code exist in a web service or as a part of an ASP.NET application (that talks directly to the browser)?

Comment: this is for web service

Answer (score 0):

If this code lives in a web service, you may be having an issue in which your application is creating a proxy between itself and your service instead of directly connecting it to the browser.

```
[Browser] ---> [ASP.NET App / Proxy] ---> [Web Service]
```

This would explain why the service is always seeing your server's IP address as the client because, from the web service point of view, the ASP.NET application IS it's "client".

In this case, the you would need to collect the client IP address at the application layer and pass it to the web service.

```
               Collect IP Address Here
                        |
                        V
[Browser] ---> [ASP.NET App / Proxy] ---> [Web Service]
                                      ^
                                      |
                              Pass IP to web Service
```